# about Brew command not found error

Tags: hebrew

i am facing the problem like brew command not found .. 
I tried the installation of package that is given but still facing same issue. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Can you please clarify what commands you ran and what packages you were trying to install?

Comment: What package you were trying to install. brew is a Mac command afaik

Answer (score 1):

To find which package have the file, head over to http://packages.ubuntu.com/ , and enter in the search box "Search content of packages" file name.

E.g. [here's the result for searching `brew`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=brew&mode=exactfilename&suite=xenial&arch=any), it's in package linuxbrew-wrapper. So you need `sudo apt install linuxbrew-wrapper`

I still didn't get though why would you want the package, given there's `apt`.